# How to safely destroy a joined multiprocessing object in a list?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using a list to keep track of all the processes being spawned in a system and want to implement a cleanup mechanism to remove the ones that are stopped. Here is a basic example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class WorkerManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process_list = []
    def spawn_process(self):
        process = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(arg1, ))
        self.process_list.append(process)
        process.start()
```

If I loop through the list and call `multiprocess.terminate()` on the processes that are not alive, I still see the objects there. How can I safely remove the references?

Note: although it's not in the sample code above, I am properly calling `multiprocessing.join()` after each worker is done.

Comment: Have you tried calling `.close()` on the process? Are you sure the process isn't still running?

Comment: What do you mean by "I still see the objects there."? Terminating the processes won't remove them from anywhere. Also, consider using `Pool` in `multiprocessing.pool` to manage multiple processes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I meant the references remain in the list even after termination. So, `self.process_list` ends up having a lot of process objects that are stopped. I wanted to remove them from the list.